# How to call method recursively with java?

Tags: java, recursion

There is java bean with list of elements and discount. I have to apply some calculate logic in those elements using recursion until that discount value gets zero.

Current implementation

```
for(CustomClass custom : customList) {
   Pair<CustomClass, Integer> returnVal = myMethod(custom, discount);
}

private Pair<CustomClass, Integer> myMethod(CustomClass custom, Integer discount) {
    pair.getKey().add(custom.setAmount(custom.getAmount - discount));
    pair.getValue().add(discount - custom.getAmount);
    return pair;
}
```

I have to do something like above and have to reuse the discount in multiple elements in the customList until it is zero. I want to make it recursive so that I get the discounted value in the CustomClass and discount is reduced.
`returnVal` has updated discount but it is not being used in next iteration.

Could someone give me good approach to solve this issue.?

Comment: *Could someone give me good approach to solve this issue* then what is the problem with current approach ?

Comment: I could not make it recursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make recursive call, you need to call same method inside

```
private Pair<CustomClass, Integer> myMethod(CustomClass custom, Integer discount) {

    int dis = discount - custom.getAmount;
    pair.getKey().add(custom.setAmount(custom.getAmount - discount))
    pair.getValue().add(dis);

    if (dis <= 0)
    {
       return pair;
    }

    return myMethod (custom, dis);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah it works.